# Angular 6 How to show Message after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm working in a project that includes a button to save a change. I just wanted a sample message shown after 3s after the button is clicked. smt like the below example

```
<div>
<button *ngIf="show" class="fade in" role="">Save</button>
   <p SOW THIS MESSAGE 3s AFTER CLICK SAVE> <strong>just Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.<p>
```

Comment: When you click the save button, create a timer, and pass a call back to set the show variable after 3 seconds

Answer (score 2):

.html:

```
<button (click)="showMessageSoon()">Show Message</button>
<p *ngIf="showMyMessage">hello there</p>
```

.ts:

```
public showMyMessage = false

showMessageSoon() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.showMyMessage = true
  }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: It works. Than you danday74. I appreciate your help.